# Another AR SDK like GART SDK on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 application with [GART SDK](https://gart.codeplex.com/).

But I don't like because it overlaps the places' names and all has the same font size. I was using ARToolkit for iPhone and it changes the font size it the places are near or far, and it doesn't overlap them.

**Do you know another SDK like GART for Windows Phone 8?**

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem a while ago, and I solved it by modifying `OnAttitudeChanged` method of `WorldView` class.

This is the code I have inside the `else` block of that method:

```cs
else
{
    // In range so show
    wvItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    // Create a CompositeTransform to position and scale the WorldViewItem
    CompositeTransform ct = new CompositeTransform();

    // Offset by half of the WorldViewItems size to center it on the point
    ct.TranslateX = projected.X - (wvItem.ActualWidth / 2);
    ct.TranslateY = projected.Y - (wvItem.ActualHeight / 2);

    // Scale should be 100% at near clipping plane and 10% at far clipping plane
    //double scale = (double)(MathHelper.Lerp(0.1f, 1.0f, (FarClippingPlane - Math.Abs(arItem.WorldLocation.Z)) / FarClippingPlane));

    // Added to use distance
    double scale = (double)(MathHelper.Lerp(0.1f, 1.0f, (FarClippingPlane - (float)Math.Round(arItem.GeoLocation.GetDistanceTo(this.Location))) / FarClippingPlane));

    // This makes the items that are far to appear higher on screen. Values are that best fit my project, so, it should be calibrated.
    ct.TranslateY = ct.TranslateY - (int)((1-scale) * 63);

    ct.ScaleX = scale;
    ct.ScaleY = scale;

    // Set the transform, which moves the item
    wvItem.RenderTransform = ct;

    // Set the items z-index so that the closest item is always rendered on top
    Canvas.SetZIndex(wvItem, (int)(scale * 255));
}
```

Comment: What exactly does it do/change? Thanks!